# Sublime: remove part of the row, in all columns

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a very big text file with multiple lines.

I want to remove a portion of the text file in every line.
This portion is at the same place for every line

For example

```
ABC.com/I_WANT_THIS_DELETED
ABC.com/I_WANT_THIS_DELETED
```

Repeat for thousand times.

I know i can press `*CONTROL + LEFT CLICK`, in order to set multiple cursors and mass delete.

But this is extremely impractical, as there are thousands of links.

How can i set a number of characters in the first row, and then select all that part for every row, so i can delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you want to delete everything after 20 characters. Open **`Find → Replace…`** and enter

```
(^.{20})(.*$)
```

in the Find field and

```
\1
```

in the Replace field. Ensure the Regular Expression and Wrap buttons are selected, then hit Replace or Replace All.

**EXPLANATION**

```
MATCH
(^.{20})        first group
 ^              start from beginning of line
  .             match any character
   {20}         20 times exactly

        (.*$)   second group
         .      match any character
          *     zero or more times
           $    until the end of the line

REPLACE
\1              replace with group 1
```

Comment: Thanks! But it didn't work for some reason. Then i went ahead and saw that i do not have sublime 3, but sublime 2... My bad.

Comment: @user1584421 I don't have Sublime 2 anymore, so I'm not sure what went wrong. Are both the Regular Expressions and Wrap buttons selected in the Find/Replace dialog? Also, I'd strongly recommend it anyway, but can you install Sublime 3 and try it there?

Comment: Yes, both buttons are selected. This is what i will do, i will update to Sublime 3. Thank you!

Comment: Worked great in Sublime 3. Thank you!